# Verfiying Network Connection in Android

Tags: android, connectivity

I want to know how to *verify the network connection* in Android  before sending data ?
Can anyone help me ?
I try this code but no results

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) 
    {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
        { 
           for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
           {
               if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'd do `.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()` like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts) question. Also duplicate thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your manifest :add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```